# Make a 3-d plot using rgl in R?

Tags: r, rgl

I have a matrix z that spits out a 20 by 20 matrix with with values starting at -9 to -739. I downloaded rgl but I can't figure out how to use it with my matrix:
z[i, j]

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
set.seed(101)
z <- matrix(sample(-739:-9,replace=TRUE,400),20)
library(rgl)
persp3d(z,col="gray")
```

[image]

Comment: You were faster. But don't you think it needs a picture?

Comment: I tried but I was having `rgl.snapshot` problems on my Ubuntu virtual machine.  Hang on ...